# Query a variable number of schemas

Tags: function, schema, plpgsql, postgresql-9.6

It's seems pretty common issue, but it's the first time I face it problem and can't find a proper solution.

I need to create a function to reference schemas dynamically, they were created with a pattern that each one have the same tables (name and columns).
At prior, only need to count records from different tables associated with the schema name.

This function I meant to use on a FROM clause, when need to look up to all schemas.

Example of output:

```
  Client  |UserName|           #post                                        |             #notification  
  schema1 | user1  |count(id) from schema1.post where post.user_id = user.id| count(id) from schema1.notif  where notif.user_id = user.id
  schema1 | user2  |count(id) from schema1.post where post.user_id = user.id| count(id) from schema1.notif  where notif.user_id = user.id
  schema2 | user3  |count(id) from schema2.post where post.user_id = user.id| count(id) from schema2.notif  where notif.user_id = user.id
```

Until now, my strategy was to create a dynamic function to set the shchema, table and column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tenant( schemaName varchar, tableName varchar, attr varchar) 
RETURNS "record" AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  temp record;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 
  'SELECT ' || attr || 
  'FROM ' || schemaName || '.' || tableName  into temp;

  RETURN temp;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

But I've got this error message when execute 
ERROR:  could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"
SQL state: 42804

Another approche is crate a function that returns a reference table. But  columns and data type should be dynamic, to be use like:

```
SELECT c.schema, u.name, 
(SELECT COUNT(post.id) from func(c.schema, 'post') AS count_post),
(SELECT COUNT(notification.id) from func(c.schema, notification') AS count_notification)   
FROM _global.customer AS c,  
_global.user AS u WHERE u.customer_id = c.id
```

Comment: Can you post content of excepted output, function and error (not image)?  Thanks.

Comment: Your select retrieves **all** rows from the the table, but tries to store it in a single `record` variable - that won't work. You should also show us how you _call_ that function.

Comment: Thank you all for the tips and patience, first time asking here.